# willpopscope is not working flutter when clicked on device backbutton

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a widget which is wrapped with `WillPopScope`:

```
Widget getBackgroundWidget() {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: AppNavigationDrawer(onSelectMenuItem),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.5,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer(),
            icon: Image.asset('assets/img/landing/title_icon.png',
                height: 30, width: 30),
          ),
          title: Text(
            AppUtils.HOME_BOTTOM_LABEL_LIST[homeCubit!.currentIndex].toUpperCase(),
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'NotoSansBold', fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

my on back pressed method is as follows:

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text(
            'Switch ION',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
          ),
          content: Text('Do you want to exit the app'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'No',
                style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'Yes',
                style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
               // Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                SystemNavigator.pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => value ?? false);
  }
```

Comment: provide more clarified information in order to make question more understandable

Comment: what kind of value is show dialog returning?

Comment: Dailog it self not showing

Comment: In that case you have to use function inside onWillPop. Like this: ```onWillPop:()async{
return await _onBackPressed();
}```. And you have to use it  as I said below, in the answers section

Comment: but this code is closing the app directly alert dialog is not showing

Answer (score 2):

`onWillPop` works according to the **bool** value it receives. I think your show dialog is not returning bool value. So you might create one **bool** variable in **_onBackPressed**. For example,

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed()async{
bool shouldPop = false
await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
      title: Text(
        'Switch ION',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
      ),
      content: Text('Do you want to exit the app'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'No',
            style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
shouldPop = false;
Navigator.pop(context)

          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Yes',
            style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
shouldPop = true;
Navigator.pop(context);
           
          },
        )
      ],
    );
return shouldPop;
}
```

So, now it should work.

Comment: alert dialog is not showing the app is closing directly

Comment: Sorry I wrote the answer here in stack overflow, so at first I forgot to use await on showdialog. So this might be the problem.

Comment: even after doing this its not working

Comment: can you share your whole using code in the update of the question please?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `then` keyword, the future function passes its result as an argument, but it is not visible outside of it. You should use `async` and `await`, that waits for the response and enables you to get its value.

With that change, your back function should be like this:

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
  final value = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: const Text(
          'Switch ION',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
        ),
        content: const Text('Do you want to exit the app'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text(
              'No',
              style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text(
              'Yes',
              style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              SystemNavigator.pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
  return value ?? false;
}
```